# Accessing NativeScript ListView itemTemplate contents

Tags: nativescript

I’m using a NativeScript `<ListView>` and I’m trying to get access to the individual elements in each element’s `<ListView.itemTemplate>`. To give a concrete example, given this code snippet, how do I access each `<GridLayout>`?

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout>...</GridLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I know that I can add a `loaded` event to each `<GridLayout>`—i.e. `<GridLayout loaded="myEventHandler">`—however, for my use case I need to change attributes on the `<GridLayout>` after an unrelated event occurs.

Theoretically I could use the `loaded` event to build an array of all `<GridLayout>`s in a `<ListView.itemTemplate>`, and then use that array to perform actions, but that just seems hacky. It seems like there has to be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: I should note that I’ve tried Nathanael’s excellent nativescript-dom plugin (https://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-dom). However, even with that approach, the contents of the templates don’t seem to be accessible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nativescript-dom plugin.   The getElementsByClassName actually has code to traverse the ListView's children.  Unfortunately after I discovered the issue and put in the bug report into the NS Common Components repo -- I totally forgot to make the same changes to the getElementsByTagName and getElementById functions in the nativescript-dom plugin.

So using getElementsByClassName if you assign it a class name should work right now.  Otherwise; I'll probably do an update to the library later this week that will have the listview children traversal code in it for the other two methods.

**Update:** I've released a new version of nativescript-dom that allows all three getElement* to work on ListView children.

Answer (score 3):

Manipulating the visual tree for a list view item doesn't seem like the most robust approach here. Consider the following scenario:

1. An item gets rendered to the screen.
2. Your code kicks in and modifies the visual container's tree.
3. The user scrolls, or something else happens, and the list view reuses the visual container for another item. Your new item now looks broken.

I'd implement this using bindings and, if things get hairy, an appropriate view model that makes bindings straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to give the each gridview and id dynamically using something like id="gridView{{$index}}" then use page.getViewById('gridView1') for example. Can't test it out at the moment, but I think that would work.

Comment: This is a clever idea, but unfortunately it doesn’t seem to work. If I try `getElementById` it can’t find elements in the templates. It’s like they’re not in the visual tree at all.